# Good Secure Skype Alternative?

Tags: video-chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure video chat program as an alternative to Skype](https://superuser.com/questions/126999/secure-video-chat-program-as-an-alternative-to-skype)

I'm looking for a secure alternative to Skype. While they were once (and arguably still are) ahead of the curve in many ways, I'm not a fan out their new direction to push business ahead of reliability.

I'm looking for a **good, secure** alternative.

By "good", it should have a decent interface and not crash at least 90% of the time I use it.

As for "secure", Skype supposedly encrypts their traffic with 256bit AES encryption, from client to client. This means theres no middleman (unless the Skype server verifies them) that can intercept my conversations. I do not want just encrypted to the server.

Comment: In what operating system(s)? Is just Windows support enough or do you need Windows/Mac OS X/Linux/mobile devices or some other combination?

Answer (score 1):

You have two sure options that meet your requirements:

first, and my favorite: Google-Talk with Video
Second, [OovoO](http://www.oovoo.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Openfire and Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) from Jive Software.  There is a GPL version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your existing applications, you can make them more secure. [Zfone is your friend.](http://zfoneproject.com/getstarted.html) And it's [secure as hell](http://www.infosecwriters.com/text_resources/pdf/Zfone_SSotillo.pdf). Made from Phil Zimmermann. I hope you know who this guy is....

if you don't mind leaving your insecure IM apps, maybe you should have a look at ["Which Instant Messaging services use or allow secure protocols, and what do those protocols cover?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/which-instant-messaging-services-use-or-allow-secure-protocols-and-what-do-those/1647#1647) from IT Security. It answers most of your questions and even more...

My answer is located at [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/which-instant-messaging-services-use-or-allow-secure-protocols-and-what-do-those/1647#1647)

I would go with Pidgin (all OSs) or Adium (mac), since they have pretty impressive security features (built-in or thru plugins), like Off-the-record messaging **(nothing to do with GTalk's "go-off-the-record")**. And the in-the-middle server(s) cannot see any of your conversation. Period. The encryption is strong and arrange by the end users. Nothing to do with the server.

If you wanna be panaroid, you can install your own Jabber server (all OS supported), use a jabber client (all free and open source) and have all your friends use jabber clients (some of them don't even require installation) and have them connect to YOUR server (can be your laptop). Again to the previous link and have a look at more details and links to resources.

[SIPcommunicator](http://sip-communicator.org/) and [Twinkle](http://www.xs4all.nl/~mfnboer/twinkle/index.html) are free, open source programs that support ZRTP encryption with many SIP services.