# Windows live messenger video encryption

Tags: encryption, windows-live-messenger, video-chat

I was searching for an alternative for Skype video chatting and I found a super user question which [recommends windows live messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/126999/secure-video-chat-program-as-an-alternative-to-skype). I used it couple of times, and then I was worried about the security of video/audio chatting.

I searched a little bit more and it turned out that [WLM video is not encrypted at all](http://windowslivehelp.com/thread.aspx?postid=F6F71366-4B07-4DC0-A5FB-702BD6F1EB8C#F6F71366-4B07-4DC0-A5FB-702BD6F1EB8C)!

Is there any plugin (I remember there was one many years ago, when it was named MSN) which add security to WLM? Or should I search for other alternative?